# Error in executing drush command

Tags: 7, drush

I am trying to execute drush command from my project root directory and i am getting following error

bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell.

Comment: is it a working drupal installation? i.e. it is connected to a database and the database is running.

Comment: yes sir other things are working fine

Comment: the problem may be due to php path conflict try this out in terminal. 

 
`$ export DRUSH_PHP='[path_to_your_php]'`

Answer (score 0):

This message occurs with a working site if the site settings.php file is not in the *sites/default* directory but a *sites/example.com* directory. In that case to specify the uri of the site you wish to address you use the syntax

`drush --uri=example.com [command`]

Comment: Would you please elaborate your comment , i have not set up multisite setup in my project. and my setting.php is in default folder only

Comment: If your settings are in sites/default/settings.php then this is not your solution. Are you executing drush from within the drupal root? What does 'drush status' provide?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the output what you get when you run the following command from your drupal root directory

```
drush status --uri="application-uri" --debug
```

You should be seeing something like below in the output

```
 Drupal version                  :  7.22

 Site URI                        :  www.xyz.com
 Database driver                 :  mysql

 Database hostname               :  localhost
 Database username               :  DB-UserName

 Database name                   :  DB-Name

 Database                        :  Connected

 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful

 Drupal user                     :  Anonymous

 Default theme                   :  seven
 Administration theme            :  seven

 PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

 Drush version                   :  5.10.0

 Drush configuration             :  /etc/drush/drushrc.php

 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/

 Site path                       :  sites/default

 File directory path             :  sites/default/files/
 Private file directory path     :  /mnt/tmp/files-private/
 Temporary file directory path   :  /mnt/tmp/
```

Check whether you could see the below.

```
Database                        :  Connected                         
Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful
```

If you see them both then you Drupal is able to connect to the Database, If not then they are not able to connect

You need to check the **settings.php** in that case.

Also let me know whether you Drupal Front end loads with out any issue